# How do I update submodule?

Tags: xcode, git

My file gitmodules is

```
[submodule "RestKit"]
    path = RestKit
    url = git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git
[submodule "restkit"]
    path = restkit
    url = git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git`enter code here`
```

My project is :

[image]

How do I update submodule?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure how to do this in XCode but you can do it in the terminal with

```
git submodule foreach \
git pull origin master
```

This will loop through all your submodules and do a `git pull` on them.